# How to change the value of a conversion in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking

i have a question on e-commerce tracking. As i know in a latter stage that a conversion is successful or not i want to be able to convert a sale as conversion but with 0 value and then when the sale is actually converted to change the value of revenue for this specific sale. Is somebody able to help on that?

Best regards and happy weekend to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell this does not really work.

If you do E-Commerce tracking you can send a second transaction using the same transaction id, and at a first glance this will look like it changed to original value; however internally this will still be recorded as two transactions and change some of your metrics (e.g. conversion rates). Also the second transaction will not be connected to the original session and will most likely be attributed to a different marketing channel. Still, this is the closest you will get to change the transaction value (and you won't be able to change goal conversion values at all).

While GA has data imports it does not have a transaction data import, and at least the free version cannot change data that is already collected (data imports only apply to newly incoming data), so this will not help you.

All in all it would be simpler/more reliable to pull the data via the API and connect it to your revenue data in a spreadsheet.